# I want to find the asymptotic complexity f(n) for the following C++ code

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
    {
        statement;
    }
}
```

I observed that the outer loop runs `rows` time and the inner loop runs `rows * cols` times and the statement runs `rows*cols` times as well. How should I put all them together to find a general function `f(n)` to find the number of steps the whole code runs so that I could find its lower and upper bounds.

Comment: You're running a nested loop. For every i (where i indicates row) it's running cols times. So overall steps will be rows * cols. As there's no additional condition to break the loop, lower bound and upper bound will be same as overall steps (rows * cols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complexity of this code is O(n²). But in your case complexity is counted as a number of steps inside the code. So if you have rows and columns (a matrix actually) then complexity is just a product of members **rows*cols**.

In more detailed way its better to count all the code that is executed in your **statement**. But for the approximation method above is good.

P.S.
To see the bounds of the code its useful to look at the graphics of the functions like f(x)=x² (in your case).